# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed

Tags: android, api

The issue happens After upgrade to API level 28. 
App crashes on android-week-view.

My Gradle
implementation 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'

Some of the suggestions says to upgrade Android Studio version 3,5 Canary 2

I upgraded my  Android Studio version on Mac to latest OS is 3.5.1
(Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203, built on September 26, 2019). Still I see the problem

containI upgraded my  Android Studio version on Mac to latest OS is 3.5.1
(Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203, built on September 26, 2019).

Comment: Have you tried AS 3.6 or 4.0?

Comment: Consider adding information to this issue if it still reproduces for you in the stable channel: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121235731

Comment: The Latest Android Studio available for Mac is 3.5.1 Android Studio 3.5.1
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203, built on September 26, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.6

Comment: Not sure why it is duplicated. None of the suggested method works for me. It is part of a library so code change option not applicable. AS version change was the other proposal. I installed the latest AS in mac. Still no luck.

Comment: Follow/upvote this library issue: https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/issues/541